# Load only subset of joined rows in SQLAlchemy ORM

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have following mapped classes defined

```
class A(Base):
    __tablename__ = "a"
    id = sqla.Column(sqla.Integer, primary_key = True)
    number_a = sqla.Column(sqla.Integer)
    b_collection = relationship('B', backref = backref('a'))

class B(Base):
    __tablename__ = "b"
    id = sqla.Column(sqla.Integer, primary_key = True)
    id_a = sqla.Column(sqla.Integer, sqla.ForeignKey('a.id'))
    number_b = sqla.Column(sqla.Integer)
```

There are these objects stored in the DB:

```
a1 = A(number_a = 1)
a2 = A(number_a = 2)
b1 = B(number_b = 50, a = a2)
b2 = B(number_b = 51, a = a2)
```

What I need is to query the relationship by issuing one query only so that it preloads `b_collection` by only results of that query:

```
result = session.query(A).join(B).filter(B.number_b == 51).all()
```

So now I would like `result[0].b_collection` to respect the filtering expression and do not include `B` instance `with number_b = 50`. So my expected output of:

```
for a in result:
    for b in a.b_collection:
        print(b.number_b)
```

would be:

```
51
```

However iterating throught `a.b_collection` allways issues a new query and loads both `B` objects into `b_collection`, so that the result is

```
50
51
```

Which is what I do not want to get.

How to enforce the original query to load all objects and populate the relationship collection according to the given filtering criteria?

Thank you for your responses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do this using [`contains_eager`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/loading_relationships.html#sqlalchemy.orm.contains_eager), but be aware that you are *tricking* SQL Alchemy, so do not reuse this *UnitOfWork* to do the regular relationship related tasks:

```
result = (
    session.query(A)
    .join(B)
    .filter(B.number_b == 51)
    .options(contains_eager(A.b_collection))  # this is the key
    ).all()
```

Comment: Thanks, that works! In what sense is it _tricking_? What are the dangers?

Comment: You are tricking the `session` to think that you *loaded* the relationship `A.b_collection`. So if you perform operations on it, they are not really representing the state of the backend database.

Comment: Yes, that is right. Understood. Thank you for the warning and for the solution.

Comment: Just little more asking: There are potentially thousands of `A` objects related to thousands of `B` objects. Imagine an operation over all these objects joined and satisfying some sql expression (constraining the result set by columns of both `A` and `B`) Then without tricking, the session would allways know about all `B` objects related to every queried `A` object and filtering over `B`s would be lost. "Tricking" sounds to me like "something bad I should avoid". Did you mean I should not do this or was it rather a "be careful" note? Any way of doing this without tricking?

Comment: I meant: *please be aware*. And in case you have many objects and do not really want to load all of them, you might consider using `lazy='dynamic'` in your relationship definition as a way of working with relationship.