# SQLAlchemy Many-to-Many outerjoin with filter

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm working with PrettyPrinted's Flask-SQLAlchemy tutorial and trying to figure out how to get a certain behavior while querying a Many-to-Many table environment.

I'll include the query I've been trying and the code for the SQLAlchemy ORM setup below.  Based on the tutorial (which doesn't go into joins or outerjoins) there are two main tables, a Channel and a User table, along with a relationship table called 'subs'.  So each user can be 'subscribed' to a channel, or more than one, or none.

What I'm trying to figure out is how to query so that I can get a list of all the rows in Channel but filter for, or have a calculated column or extra column to indicate only the ones that a particular user id is 'subscribed' to.  So all would be returned, just an extra column (or not null data in a column) for the ones the selected user subscribes to.

Here is the query I've been trying (tried a few others but with even less luck):

```
chan_query = Channel.query.outerjoin(User, User.user_id==1).all()
```

The problem being that this returns not only all the rows in Channel (which I do want it to do), but when I dive into each row instead of just having a null and not null, or anything that would indicate just the selected user id being subscribed it lists ALL the users that are subscribed to each channel.  The only way I've been able to emulate what I'm trying to do is with two queries - one for all the Channels, one for all the channels that the user is subscribed to, and then using a comprehension to build what I'm hoping to get with a single query.  Not very pythonic or good practice on data management.

Can someone point me in the direction of what I'm doing wrong and how to learn to fix it?  Thank you so much!

Below is the code for the ORM tables being used:

```
subs = db.Table('subs',
    db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.user_id')),
    db.Column('channel_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('channel.channel_id'))
)


class User(db.Model):
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(20))
    subscriptions = db.relationship('Channel', secondary=subs, backref=db.backref('subscribers', lazy='dynamic'))


class Channel(db.Model):
    channel_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    channel_name = db.Column(db.String(20))
```

Comment: Could you include a sample of what you're hoping to get, or what you're doing at the moment to get it?

Comment: Possibly somewhat related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28678443/load-only-subset-of-joined-rows-in-sqlalchemy-orm