# Load `relationship` with subset of items in SqlAlchemy (similar to Django's `Prefetch` object)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, relationship, loading

Is there a way to retrieve a subset of elements from a relationship in SqlAlchemy but keeping the order I defined in the `backref` (relationship) when the class was created?

Let's say I have two tables/models: A `User` and a `UserLog` which contains actions performed by the user (the `Base` is just a [declarative_base()](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/declarative/index.html))

Each `UserLog` has a ForeignKey to the ID of the `User` that performed the action, and the type of action for each log can be chosen from an `Enum`. Each UserLog also has a `created` timestamp I order with: On a regular scenario, I'd like to get the logs from oldest to newest (oldest first).

However, I'd also like to be able to get a particular user with only a subset of Logs (logs of a particular action) loaded. I understand this goes agains the "gist" of the joined load, since I would be getting an unrealistic state of the database (there are more logs linked to the user that my fetched `User` object would reflect), but it would be helpful in certain occasions.

```
class UserLog(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user_logs'
    id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True)
    timestamp_created = Column(
        DateTime, server_default=sqlalchemy.text("now()")
    )
    user_id = Column(
        UUID(as_uuid=True),
        ForeignKey("users.id", ondelete="CASCADE")
    )
    action = Column(SaEnum(UserLogsConstants), nullable=False)

    user = relationship(
        "User", 
        backref=backref(
          'logs', order_by="asc(UserLog.timestamp_created)"
        ) # The order_by is important here
    )
```

Thanks [to this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28679099/289011) I've been able to load a subset of logs using [`contains_eager`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/loading_relationships.html#using-contains-eager-to-load-a-custom-filtered-collection-result), but then I lose the ordering by `timestamp_created` that I stated in the `backref`.

Let's say I have two available actions for the logs: `UPLOAD_START`, `UPLOAD_END` (for the `action` column)

I've set up a test in which I create a `User` with 5 `UPLOAD_START` actions and 5 `UPLOAD_END` actions created **out of order** (I'm *artificially* inserting "newer" actions first).

So what I'd like is getting a `User` with its `.logs` relationship containing *only* logs whose event is `UPLOAD_START` *and* keep the order by timestamp specified in the `backref` object.

Here's the test query

```
u = session.query(User) \
    .filter(User.id == test_user_id) \
    .join(User.logs) \
    .filter(UserLog.action == UserLogsConstants.UPLOAD_START) \
    .options(contains_eager(User.logs)) \
    .one()
```

These two asserts work fine:

```
assert len(u.logs) == 5  
# I inserted 10 logs total, only 5 with action=UPLOAD_START

assert all(ul.action == UserLogsConstants.UPLOAD_START for ul in u.logs)
# Neat, only logs with `UPLOAD_START`
```

But this one fails: the ordering is not respected.

```
assert all(
    u.logs[i].timestamp_created < u.logs[i + 1].timestamp_created
    for i in range(len(u.logs) - 1)
)
```

That makes sense. If I understand the `contains_eager` behavior, this is kind of a *forget what you think the relationship is, and use what I'm telling you in the preceding query* (and I'm not saying anything about the order in that query). And, indeeed: I'm looking at the SQL generated by SqlAlchemy and there's no `ORDER BY` clause. I suppose I could always add it myself to the query, but if would be cleaner if I didn't need to.

For those familiar with Django, I'm kind of trying to emulate the [`Prefech`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Prefetch) object, where I can specify a subquery to get the loaded objects from:

```
User.objects.prefetch_related(
     Prefetch(
         'logs', 
         queryset=UserLogs.objects.filter(action=UserLogsConstants.UPLOAD_START)
     )
).get(pk='foo-uuid')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using `contains_eager`, you tell SQLAlchemy to ignore the configured relationship and instead fill the `.logs` container from your hand-crafted query. That means any ordering set on the relationship is also ignored.

So if you need the log data to be ordered, you need to do so yourself:

```
u = (
    session.query(User)
        .filter(User.id == test_user_id)
        .join(User.logs)
        .filter(UserLog.action == UserLogsConstants.UPLOAD_START)
        .order_by(User.id, asc(UserLog.timestamp_created))
        .options(contains_eager(User.logs))
        .one()
)
```

If you are more commonly filtering user logs, then another option is to make `logs` a [dynamic relationship](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/collections.html#dynamic-relationship-loaders). This replaces the container with a pre-populated `Query` object you'd filter on:

```
user = relationship(
    "User", 
    backref=backref(
      'logs', lazy='dynamic', order_by="asc(UserLog.timestamp_created)"
    )
)
```

and use

```
u = session.query(User).filter(User.id == test_user_id).one()
upload_start_logs = u.logs.filter(UserLog.action == UserLogsConstants.UPLOAD_START).all()
```

Of course, this does issue a separate query.